# How to add built-in test event to lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, unit-testing, aws-lambda

I have several lambda functions in my project.
For each function I have an event file that is used for local test purposes.

I wonder to know how can I attached these events files to my lambda function inside the aws-console as test event, so I will not need to create a new event each time after code deployment.

Seems like my answer involves with template.yaml file but I couldn't find the answer over the web.

Comment: You may want to save your test events as [Shareable test events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/testing-functions.html). Those should not be deleted automatically.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

You cannot add or seed pre-existing 'test events' for a Lambda function - they're meant to just be an easy way of invoking your Lambda from within the console itself.

You will have to recreate them manually unless you are using shareable test events.

Comment: I want to have a list of test events that me as a developer I will be able to pick one of them and test my function in aws-console. It should be an easy way, thats why im looking for such a solution

Comment: @roeygol I understand - this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for [Shareable Test Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/testing-functions.html#creating-shareable-events).

> Shareable test events are test events that you can share with other AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) users in the same AWS account. You can edit other users' shareable test events and invoke your function with them.

**To create a shareable test event**

1. Open the Functions page of the Lambda console.
2. Choose the name of the function that you want to test.
3. Choose the Test tab.
4. Choose a Template.
5. Enter a Name for the test.
6. In the text entry box, enter the JSON test event.
7. Under Event sharing settings, choose Shareable.
8. Choose Save changes.